# node.js timeout / task scheduling

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, settimeout, cleartimeout

I'm working on node application that would monitor user's online status. It uses socket.io to update online status for users we "observe" (as in, the users we are aware of on the page we're at). What I would like to introduce now is `idle` status, which would basically mean that after X time of inactivity (as in no request) the status would change from `online` to `idle`.

I do monitor all the sockets thus I know when connection was made, so I thought of using this.

My idea is to use setTimeout on every connection for this particular uses (clearing out the previous one if exists) and in setTimeout I would simply change user's status to `idle` and emit that status change to observers.

What I'm concerned about is performance and scalability of setting and clearning the timeout on every connection. So the question is, are there any issues in terms of the two above with such approach? Is there a better thing of doing it, perhaps a library that is better at handling such things?

Comment: How many concurrent users?

Comment: Well, hard to tell because people usually use multiple tabs as well. I'd say it's about 100-250 currently, but it should scale well as much as it can. I'd say up to what node can handle itself.

Comment: From what I'm reading here and there, hundreds or even a few thousand active timers shouldn't impose a big performance impact, and should also be relatively easy to implement for testing purposes. Alternatively, you could implement some sort of idle timer class that stores the last message timestamp for each socket and periodically (using `setInterval`) checks which sockets have become idle.

Comment: @robertklep I see, well, I think I will just have to test it. I did think about utilizing `setInterval` (since it's gonna be time about 30 minutes~ I don't mind +/- 15 seconds, so it can run with 15s interval) and just use some container (with duplicate key checks & ordered by value) to store connection times. Do you think it would perform better than using timers then?

Comment: I don't really know, tbh, but gut feeling says that having one timer that periodically fires is a bit more scalable.

Comment: This is my feeling too :) but since the question is related to setTimout and its performance, I suppose this answers my question. I will only need to test which one would be better : ) I also read somewhere than execution of these scheduled stuff blocks node app, perhaps setTimeout would be better in that case, because it will take much less time to execute a single timeout compared to periodical executions of "aggregated" handler. But will check it out. Thank you for your suggestions.